# Hiding multiple sheets based on multiple cell values in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook which has multiple sheets including 19 data entry sheets. I want to hide the corresponding data entry sheets if the value in any of the rows `(E14:E45)` in sheet `"IEP"` is `"N"` and `unhide` those sheets having value `"Y"`.

I've tried `Case` statement as well as `If Else` both but both work partially.

```
Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Excel.Range)
Worksheets.IEP.Range ("E14")

Case "N"
If [E14] = "N" Then
Worksheets("ADL-Eat").Visible = False
Else
End If
If [E15] = "N" Then
Worksheets("ADL-Drink").Visible = False
Else
End If
If [E16] = "N" Then
Worksheets("ADL-T").Visible = False
Else
End If
If [E17] = "N" Then
Worksheets("ADL-Dres").Visible = False
Else
End If
If [E18] = "N" Then
Worksheets("CBD").Visible = False
Else
End If
If [E19] = "N" Then
Worksheets("DA").Visible = False
Else
End If
If [E20] = "N" Then
Worksheets("SE-A").Visible = False
Else
End If
If [E21] = "N" Then
Worksheets("SE-GK").Visible = False
Else
End If
If [E22] = "N" Then
Worksheets("Social").Visible = False
Else
End If
If [E23] = "N" Then
Worksheets("SA").Visible = False
Else
End If
If [E24] = "N" Then


End Select
End Sub


  Private Sub worksheet_change(ByVal target As Excel.Range)
    Worksheets.IEP.Range ("E14")

    Case "Y"

    If [E14] = "Y" Then
    Worksheets("ADL-Eat").Visible = True
    Else
    End If
    If [E15] = "Y" Then
    Worksheets("ADL-Drink").Visible = True
    Else
    End If
    If [E16] = "Y" Then
    Worksheets("ADL-T").Visible = True
    Else
    End If
    If [E17] = "Y" Then
    Worksheets("ADL-Dres").Visible = True
    Else
    End If
    If [E18] = "Y" Then
    Worksheets("CBD").Visible = True
    Else
    End If
    If [E19] = "Y" Then
    Worksheets("DA").Visible = True
    Else
    End If
    If [E20] = "Y" Then
    Worksheets("SE-A").Visible = True
    Else
    End If
    If [E21] = "Y" Then
    Worksheets("SE-GK").Visible = True
    Else
    End If
    If [E22] = "Y" Then
    Worksheets("Social").Visible = True
    Else
    End If
    If [E23] = "Y" Then
    Worksheets("SA").Visible = True
    Else
    End If
    If [E24] = "Y" Then
    Worksheets("FS").Visible = True
    Else
    End If


    End Select
    End Sub
```

I expected those sheets to be hidden when the value in rows is `"N"` but actual output is that they are visible even when the value is `"N"`.

Comment: please reformat your post for better clarity

Comment: My workbook is for compiling intellectually challenged children's daily progress record in 19 different activities e.g. "ADL-Eat", "ADL-Drink", "ADL-T", "ADL-Dres" etc. Workbook contains total 27 sheets including 19 sheets meant for data entry to be done by teachers. All these sheets are listed in column "D" in Sheet "IEP". I want to hide those data entry sheets which are not needed for a child. The sheets to be hidden are identified by the value in the rows (E14:E45) in sheet "IEP" as "N" and visible sheets having value "Y".

Answer (score 0):

[image: Sample Worksheet]

If you're worksheet looks like this, you can try below code:

```
Sub showHideWS()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IEP") 'Name of the primary worksheet

Dim wsName As String

For a = 14 To 45
    wsName = sh.Range("D" & a).Value
        If wsName <> "" Then
        If sh.Range("E" & a).Value = "N" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsName).Visible = False
        Else
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsName).Visible = True
        End If
    End If
Next a
End Sub
```